# How can I insert a row of NULL values at the top of each matrix in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

I want to insert a new row to a matrix so as to solve the problem of array index out of bounds when using a function like `prev` in DolphinDB.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from DolphinDB 1.30.17, when the rowIndex or columnIndex is out of bounds, NULL values will be generated. You can also use the function `concatMatrix` to concatenate matrices vertically or horizontally.